# How should you live when you have options?

Tags: ethics, meaning-of-life, possible-worlds, work, money

If you have the opportunity to earn money easily (for example just doing dropshipping, or selling oil reserve) which requires less self control and discipline. And the other is by doing difficult job (for example engineering, solving problems) which requires a lot of self control, hardwork and discipline. Which path should you choose? If you can earn money easily why should you go for the challenging path? What is the point in challenging and pushing you in this situation.

Comment: Who said "challenging" can't be fun or interesting or challenging? Some people want to push the boundaries of what can be done and/or what they can achieve. This in itself can be way more rewarding than simply going along

Comment: By doing what you [value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology). If it is money or easy life so be it, but for most it is not. "*Nothing in the world is worth having or worth doing unless it means effort, pain, difficulty… I have never in my life envied a human being who led an easy life. I have envied a great many people who led difficult lives and led them well,*" Roosevelt.